# English Words in Tosfot?

Tags: history, translation, language, tosfot

Posting for someone else:

Rashi occasionally provides Old French words in his commentary to help understand certain terms or concepts. Who is the earliest author to have done the same with (Old) English words (if anyone has)? Did any of the [English Tosafists](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tosafot_Hachmei_Anglia) do this? (Note: I don't consider an early English translation of the Torah to be an answer to this question).

Comment: https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=147543&pagenum=16 list of laaz in tosafos

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel This link looks like it contains a number of potential answers.

Comment: My impression was that the Jewish population in England at the time were culturally French. E.g. a Gett given in London back then said "Londres." So I wouldn't expect to see Old English, just Old French.

Comment: Was English language spoken at the time of Tosfot or vernacular language?

Comment: A rebbe in telz showed me a rashi that said cucumber in 8th grade. Don't remember where tho.

Comment: @KovyJacob its in behaalotcha. However, that's a french word, like many other examples

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For example the Mishna on Megilla 17a בסם is translated as מין [קולורא](https://beta.otzar.org/#/b/9013/p/56/t/1646348169121/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c/1646356599009). Sounds like color.

Comment: This belongs in the comment section.

Comment: Folks I'm quoting the english tosafists they also said grape and ember

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Got it, thanks! But maybe make that clearer in the answer...

Comment: The English word derives from French, so how do you know this is English and not French? Same with grape.

Comment: The English Tosafists probably spoke some version of French, especially since they were very connected to the French Jewish community and French was a major spoken language in southern England at the time.

Comment: @magicker72 your comment makes sense for color (couleur in French), less for grape (raisin in French, grappe also exists but means a bunch, so grappe de raisin is a bunch of raisins)

Comment: @mbloch Google ["grape etymology"](https://www.google.com/search?q=grape+etymology&oq=grape+etym&aqs=chrome.0.0i512j69i60j69i57j0i22i30j0i10i22i30l2j0i22i30j0i10i22i30.3139j0j7&client=ms-android-google&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8). Remember, English is being influenced by 11th century French, not modern French.

Comment: Guys, colour is coming from Latin...